# Neo4j GRASS stylesheet: how to show node or relationship id

Tags: css, neo4j

Is it possible to use the id of a node or relationship in the stylesheet?

Currently, I know that node property values can be used through `{property-name}`, relationship types can be used through `<type>`, but I do not know whether or how to get at the id; I've tried `{id}` (which shouldn't work) and `<id>` (which seemed plausible), but neither works.

Answer (score 1):

It works you have to use

```
caption: '<id>';
```

As you can see when you select the id field manually and then inspect the GRASS.

Comment: That seems to work only for relationships. (Neo4j 3.0.6)